# Setting cookies not taking effect in Safari

Tags: apex, managed-package, browser, cookies

We have a managed package and are attempting to set a cookie using Apex code as follows:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{key});
```

The cookie seems to be set correctly in Opera, Firefox, IE, and Chrome, but Safari doesn't seem to take the cookie. No error messages, the cookie simply doesn't show up. We've tried in several different Safari versions but no dice.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: One quick question what version of Safari/Platform ?

Comment: @JamesKn Latest version of Safari (9) but also tested back to 7. SF developer edition.

Comment: What are the settings in Safari for cookies? Always Allow?

Comment: Default settings.

Answer (score 1):

I tested again the cookie set on a visual force page running on Safari and to cookie seems to set correctly.

[image]

I didn't use managed package to test so maybe there is still a difference there, but could you test it in the developer org where you build your package and run it there does it give the same result?

This is the code i used (standaard workbook help article code)

```
public with sharing class testCookieController {

public testCookieController(){

   Cookie counter = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('counter');

    // If this is the first time the user is accessing the page,
    // create a new cookie with name 'counter', an initial value of '1',
    // path 'null', maxAge '-1', and isSecure 'false'.
    if (counter == null) {
        counter = new Cookie('counter','1',null,-1,false);
    } else {
    // If this isn't the first time the user is accessing the page
    // create a new cookie, incrementing the value of the original count by 1
        Integer count = Integer.valueOf(counter.getValue());
        counter = new Cookie('counter', String.valueOf(count+1),null,-1,false);
    }

    ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{counter});


}
```